# Stylus Cannot set property 'lineno' of undefined

Tags: stylus

For any .styl file in my project folder Stylus output is

```
Cannot set property 'lineno' of undefined

    at Lexer.advance (C:\Projects\my-project\node_modules\stylus\lib\lexer.js:229:16)
    at Lexer.lookahead (C:\Projects\my-project\node_modules\stylus\lib\lexer.js:119:46)
    at Lexer.peek (C:\Projects\my-project\node_modules\stylus\lib\lexer.js:242:17)
    at Parser.peek (C:\Projects\my-project\node_modules\stylus\lib\parser.js:324:23)
    at Parser.accept (C:\Projects\my-project\node_modules\stylus\lib\parser.js:272:22)
    at Parser.selector (C:\Projects\my-project\node_modules\stylus\lib\parser.js:1538:12)
    at Parser.stmt (C:\Projects\my-project\node_modules\stylus\lib\parser.js:778:26)
    at Parser.statement (C:\Projects\my-project\node_modules\stylus\lib\parser.js:685:21)
    at Parser.block (C:\Projects\my-project\node_modules\stylus\lib\parser.js:852:21)
    at Parser.selector (C:\Projects\my-project\node_modules\stylus\lib\parser.js:1555:24)
    at Parser.stmt (C:\Projects\my-project\node_modules\stylus\lib\parser.js:778:26)
    at Parser.statement (C:\Projects\my-project\node_modules\stylus\lib\parser.js:685:21)
    at Parser.block (C:\Projects\my-project\node_modules\stylus\lib\parser.js:852:21)
    at Parser.selector (C:\Projects\my-project\node_modules\stylus\lib\parser.js:1555:24)
    at Parser.stmt (C:\Projects\my-project\node_modules\stylus\lib\parser.js:778:26)
    at Parser.statement (C:\Projects\my-project\node_modules\stylus\lib\parser.js:685:21)
```

I am running Stulus with command: `stylus -w filename.styl -o style.css`

Stylus version is 0.54.5.

What could be the reason of that?

Comment: What kind of indenting are you using? Try to change it to tabs and re run it, if not working, please show us the .styl file

Answer (score 1):

After some digging I found that one of my .styl files was in UTF-16 instead of UTF-8.
I changed encoding to UTF-8 and it fixed the problem.